# converting a linux shell script command into php

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm facing a problem that probably has an easy solution, but as I'm not a php expert I can not find it. I usually do this when I have to call a shell command from php:

```
cmd = "convert file.pdf image.jpg";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

But now I have a command that works on the shell that I can not make it run from the php, so I think there is probably a way to enunciate the same command but in php language,

*the command:*

```
for i in $(seq --format=%3.f 0 $nf); do echo doing OCR on page $i; tesseract '$imgdir/$imgdir-$i.ppm' '$imgdir-$i' -l eng; done
```

*my php try:*

```
<?php
$imgdir = "1987_3";
$nf = count(new GlobIterator('filesup/'.$imgdir.'/*'));
$cmd = "for i in $(seq --format=%3.f 0 $nf); do echo doing OCR on page $i; tesseract '$imgdir/$imgdir-$i.ppm' '$imgdir-$i' -l eng; done"
shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

*What I get is:*

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: i in count.php on line 7
```

suggestions are very welcomed...  thanks

**UPDATE**

I have read the question from the one I'm marked as possible duplicated, and what I understood from that was that my "i" have to have a reference, which, for a shell command, it has, but it does not work when executed from php.

In regard of that I also tried this unsuccessfuly:

```
<?php
$imgdir = "1987_3";
$nf = count(new GlobIterator('filesup/'.$imgdir.'/*'));
$cmd ="seq --format=%3.f 0 $nf";
$i = shell_exec($cmd);
$cmd = "tesseract 'filesup/$imgdir/$imgdir-$i.jpg' 'filesup/$imgdir/$imgdir-$i' -l eng; done";
shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP** will evaluate all variables inside a string with double quotes, example:

```
<?php
    $i=5;
    echo "Your i is: $i";
?>
```

**output**: `Your i is: 5`

If you want to avoid this behaivor, use a simple quote:

```
<?php
    $i=5;
    echo 'Your i is: $i';
?>
```

**output**: `Your i is: $i`

Update your code like this:

```
<?php
    $imgdir = "1987_3";
    $nf = count(new GlobIterator('filesup/'.$imgdir.'/*'));
    $cmd = 'for i in $(seq --format=%3.f 0 $nf); do echo doing OCR on page $i; tesseract \'' . $imgdir/$imgdir . '-$i.ppm\' \'' . $imgdir . '-$i\' -l eng; done';    
    shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had to do some minor adjustments to the code, but it did work, thanks again!